# Android Getting Contact List is not Showing in Android 10

Tags: android, kotlin, android-contacts, android-contentresolver, android-10.0

I am trying to get contact list in android. It is working fine in andorid 6 and 7. But when I run the same code in andorid 10 it is not showing any single contact. Is there any changes in Android 10?
Here is my Code:

```
 private fun prepareData() {
        contactList.clear()
        val cur: Cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null)!!
        if (cur.count > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                val id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID))
                val cur1: Cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", arrayOf(id), null)!!
                while (cur1.moveToNext()) {
                    //to get the contact data
                    val name = cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME))
                    val phoneticName = cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHONETIC_NAME))
                    val phoneNumber = getPhoneNumber()
                    val email = cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA))

                    Log.d("Email", "name: " + name)
                    Log.d("Email", "phoneticName: " + phoneticName)
                    Log.d("Email", "phoneNumber: " + phoneNumber)
                    Log.d("Email", "email: " + email)

                    contactList.add(Contact(if (name.isNotEmpty()) name else "", if (phoneNumber.isNotEmpty()) phoneNumber else "",
                                    if (phoneticName.isNotEmpty()) phoneticName.trim() else "", if (email.isNotEmpty()) email else ""))
                }
                cur1.close()
            }
        }

        if (contactList.isEmpty()) {
            recyclerView!!.visibility = View.GONE
        } else {
            recyclerView!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            mAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you getting any error ?

Answer (score 2):

[Runtime permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) were introduced in Android 6.0 (Api level 23), but technically you could still run apps on Android 6 without supporting Runtime Permissions by targeting lower APIs, I don't think that's possible anymore in Android 10 (or even lower).

Does your app asks for `Runtime permission` `READ_CONTACTS` to be able to access the `ContactsContract` APIs?

Also, I don't think your code works well in ANY Android version, you can't query `CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI` and then get phone numbers, I suppose you only get names + emails from this code.

Also your code is highly inefficient, it runs a query per contact which may result in hundreds of queries taking some time.
You should replace this with a single query like this (supporting both emails and phones):

```
val projection: Array<out String> = arrayOf(Data.CONTACT_ID, Data.DISPLAY_NAME, Data.PHONETIC_NAME, Data.MIMETYPE, Data.DATA1)
val selection: String = Data.MIMETYPE + " IN ('" + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "', '" + Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "')"

val map = mutableMapOf<Long, Contact>() // map contact-id to Contact object

val cur: Cursor = contentResolver.query(Data.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null)!!
while (cur.moveToNext()) {
    val id = cur.getLong(0)
    val name = cur.getString(1)
    val phoneticName = cur.getString(2)
    val mimetype = cur.getString(3) // this tells us if this row is a phone or email row
    val data = cur.getString(4) // may hold either phone or email
    
    Log.d("Contact", id + " " + name + " " + mimetype + " " + data)

    val contact = map[id]
    if (contact == null) {
        contact = Contact(name, "", phoneticName, "") // create a new contact without email or phone
        map[id] = contact
    }

    if (mimetype == Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE) {
        contact.phone = data
    } else {
        contact.email = data
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your code is giving data fine but it is showing double data. Don't know why it is showing doubling data. kindly update it so it don't show double contact.
name: Zeeshan name: Zeeshan
name: Adnan name: Adnan

Comment: we're iterating through a list of data rows, which means if a contact has 2 emails and 3 phones we'll visit this contact 5 times in the while loop. that's why i'm using a map from contact-id to contact-object. if you see multiple logs for the same contact in logcat that's ok

Comment: But this will also show double contact data in our ListView.

Comment: how are you using the `map` that this code outputs? since this is a map each contact-id has to appear only once by definition

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. Actually my code is also working fine. Android 10 don't have concept of phoneticName and that's why it was crashing. Anyone can use my code by just removing phoneticName it will work perfectly. Thanks!